# Is it possible to set ServerName with an environment variable in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd.conf

How can I set the `ServerName` directive in Apache to the environment variable `HTTP_HOST`

I have tried:

```
ServerName %{HTTP_HOST} #or ServerName ${HTTP_HOST} or expr=%{HTTPS}
```

```
Define server_name %{HTTP_HOST} #or ${HTTP_HOST} or expr=%{HTTPS}
```

Nothing works. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's not possible, and you don't even need it.** If this was possible, it would conflict with the [Virtual Host Matching](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/details.html). As the `HTTP_HOST` server variable contains the value of the `Host:` header, it would mean that it always matches every request. Apache already works like that: if there's not a matching VirtualHost, it will use the first name-based virtual host for that IP and port.

> The first name-based vhost in the configuration file for a given
>   IP:port pair is significant because it is used for all requests
>   received on that address and port for which no other vhost for that
>   IP:port pair has a matching `ServerName` or `ServerAlias`. It is also used
>   for all SSL connections if the server does not support [Server Name
>   Indication](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/glossary.html#servernameindication).

Therefore, having only a single name based virtual host would be identical to what you are probably trying to do with your `ServerName %{HTTP_HOST}`.

Comment: When I don't use ServerName, it just uses my server hostname like `my-server.servername.com`, why? It doesn't display the host header?

Comment: See the **ServerName inheritance** from [Name-based Virtual Host Support](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html): "It is best to always explicitly list a `ServerName` in every name-based virtual host.

If a `VirtualHost` doesn't specify a `ServerName`, a server name will be inherited from the base server configuration. If no server name was specified globally, one is detected at startup through reverse DNS resolution of the first listening address."